# Mapping a large list of addresses to (longitude, latitude) coordinates

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a list of over 250,000 addresses I need to convert to longitude, latitude pairs. I found two solutions online:

```
import requests
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim()

def lonlat(address):
    address = address.replace(' ', '+')
    response = requests.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%s' % address)
    resp_json_payload = response.json()
    return resp_json_payload['results'][0]['geometry']['location']

def lonlat2(address):
    location = geolocator.geocode(address)
    try:
        return (location.longitude, location.latitude)
    except:
        return address
```

Neither of these methods are scalable to over 250,000 addresses; I'm not even sure what the API limits are either. What are suitable work-arounds?

Comment: People are likely to downvote this because you might be asking for an API recommendation, which SO doesn't do.

Comment: The API limits are documented [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits). There's really no way to "work around" that. You can pay for higher limits, you can perform the requests over multiple days (or both), or you can research other geocoding services with different limits. It is unlikely you will find a free service that will handle 250,000 requests.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google's Geocoding API up to 100k requests per day for 50 USD.  The Enterprise contract allows even more than that (and will obviously cost more).

So in three days you can convert all your addresses for about 125 USD.  You'll hit the rate limit in about 34 minutes each day if you use the maximum allowed 50 queries per second.

Ref: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits